# How to set image as the background in spainter js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to use an image as background image in spainter.

[image]

I use context.drawImage() to set image into canvas but not working.

here my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spainter@1.0.0/index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spainter@1.0.1/index.css"/>
<div id="containerPainter"></div>
<script>
var p = new Painter(containerPainter);
var context = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
 base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGZtm.png';
  context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
</script>
```

So, I need your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to draw the image after it has been loaded. Using `onload` listener will work for you like so :-

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spainter@1.0.0/index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/spainter@1.0.1/index.css"/>
<div id="containerPainter"></div>
<script>
var p = new Painter(containerPainter);
var context = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
 base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGZtm.png';
  base_image.onload = () => context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
</script>
```

It seems to work if the image is a blob. Here is that code (posting since StackOverflow doesn't allow going over certain character limits) :-

https://codepen.io/lapstjup/pen/YzZNWEX

Comment: THIS NOT WORK ANYMORE

Comment: WHILE I DRAW IT SHOW ERROR

Comment: Another answer? @LakshyaThakur

Comment: Can you check the codepen link I shared ? Converting the same image to a blob and painting over it works somehow. Not sure of the reason yet. Also converting to blob could have worked via code. `fetch+URL.createObjectURL` helps us achieve that but when trying to `fetch` image , getting cors error. That's why the hardcoded blob.

Comment: I obtained the blob using [this](https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64) website where I simply uploaded your png to get the **data:uri**.